# How to get maximum results for API when default is set to 500

Tags: python, api, url

The default results returned for this API is 500 https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas

I want to get the maximum number of results using Python but I can only set the _limit to a higher amount. How should I go about finding it?

Additional info below:
https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/doc/reference#flood-areas

Used this to get an increased limit 
https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/?_limit=100000

Answer (score 0):

what I'd normally do would be to send multiple requests, one for each "page" of results, with progressively higher offsets. e.g. you'd do something like:

```
import requests

url = 'https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas'
offset = 0
result = []

while True:
  res = requests.get(url, params={'_offset': offset})
  res.raise_for_status()

  data = res.json()
  items = data['items']
  if not items:
    break

  result.extend(items)
  offset += len(items)
```

there are multiple reasons for their API working like this, one common one is to try and reduce the impact of denial of service attacks.  it's easy for attackers to put a few more zeros on the limit causing the server to do exponentially more work.  conversely, once you get above a few hundred objects returned from this service the extra work of paging HTTP requests will always be a small percentage of the total work performed, and keeps clients "honest"